# Context Free Grammar for a specific lanuage

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar

I want a context free grammar for the language `L={ww | w belongs to 0*10*}`.

I tried the following grammar:

```
S->K1KK1K
K->0K | 1K | e
```

but i know that is wrong. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: you should use the fact that your strings are of the form 0^n 1 0^(m+n) 1 0^m.

Answer (score 0):

S->A1A

A->BA|e

B->0

As you can see , here A->BA represents 0*(0 closure).

Comment: Thank you for answer but the language is ww and not only w and w belongs to 0*10* –

Comment: Ok ! i will check its solution in my textbook. This time i'll be back with a correct answer . :D